# Unable to dynamically locate map boundary coordinates in OSM/Leaflet

Tags: javascript, cartography, leaflet, coordinates

I have been trying for the past hour to take the coordinates of the map edge in a OSM/leaflet application I am making. While I can get the coordinates of the center, and I can get the coordinates of the two poinths the user inputs, the bounds of the map remain unchanging and static on the ones the map loaded. I think it has to do with the map.setView() I call in the start of the code, but I am not sure how to fix that. The code is as follows (the problematic part is actually on the lower part of the code):

```
var map = L.map('map').setView([37.92,23.69], 13);
var bounds=map.getBounds();
var nodeArray=new Array();
var markerArray = new Array();
var startPoint=null;
var endPoint=null;
var lowerBounds=bounds.getSouthWest();
var upperBounds=bounds.getNorthEast();
var markerCounter=0;



L.tileLayer('http://{s}.tile.osm.org/{z}/{x}/{y}.png', {
attribution: 'Map data &copy; <a href="http://openstreetmap.org">OpenStreetMap</a> contributors, <a href="http://creativecommons.org/licenses/by-sa/2.0/">CC-BY-SA</a>, Imagery © <a href="http://cloudmade.com">CloudMade</a>',
maxZoom: 18}).addTo(map);

var popup = L.popup();
var road = L.polyline(nodeArray).addTo(map);

map.on('click', onMapClick);
function onMapClick(e) {
    markerCounter=markerArray.length;
    if (markerCounter==2){
        map.removeLayer(markerArray[0]);
        map.removeLayer(markerArray[1]);
        markerArray=new Array();
        endPoint=null;
        startPoint=null;
    }else{
        var marker = new L.Marker(e.latlng, {draggable:false});
        markerArray.push(marker);
        for (i=0;i<=markerArray.length;i++){
            map.addLayer(marker);
        }
        if (markerCounter==1){
            marker.bindPopup("Your destination is: "+(e.latlng.toString()).substr(6,20)).openPopup();
            endPoint=(e.latlng.toString()).substr(6,20);
            markerCounter=2;
        }
        if (markerCounter==0){
            marker.bindPopup("Your starting place is: "+(e.latlng.toString()).substr(6,20)).openPopup();
            startPoint=(e.latlng.toString()).substr(6,20);
            markerCounter=1;
        }

    }
};

function runScript(){
    if (markerCounter==0){
        alert('You have give us no data. We cannot calculate a route');
    }else if (markerCounter==1){
        alert('You have give us only one point. We cannot calculate a route');
    }else{
        console.log('LB:'+lowerBounds+" - "+"UB:"+upperBounds+"/SP:"+startPoint+" - EP:"+endPoint);
        } 
}
```

Does anyone have any idea what is the problem?I am unfortunately entirely new to JS and OSM/Leaflet, so I cannot really see easily problems like those.

Comment: I don't see you using `map.getBounds()` anywhere after the map is initilized. You are using `var bounds=map.getBounds();` only once. And that is before you fully initilize the map.

Comment: Thanks! I forgot to add the code before I request the lower/upper bounds.

Answer (score 1):

You must update your variable `bounds` every time you want to access the current bounds of the map. In your code, this would look like this:

```js
function runScript() {
  ...
  else {
    bounds = map.getBounds()
    lowerBounds = bounds.getSouthWest()
    upperBounds = bounds.getNorthEast()
    console.log('LB:'+lowerBounds+" - "+"UB:"+upperBounds+"/SP:"+startPoint+" - EP:"+endPoint)
  }
}
```

Alternatively you could bind a listener to the map that fires on [`moveend`](https://leafletjs.com/reference-1.3.4.html#map-moveend):

```js
map.on("moveend", (e) => { 
    // updates always after map has been moved 
    bounds = map.getBounds()
    lowerBounds = bounds.getSouthWest()
    upperBounds = bounds.getNorthEast()
})
```